# Jar file runs by double clicking but not through cmd?

Tags: java, cmd, jar

I made a small Java application that I wanted to send to my friend, however they cannot open the file by double clicking it. They have no technical knowledge or experience so I can't really get them to use any other means to run the application.

It seems the application runs just fine when I try double clicking it, however when I tried running through CMD (using `java -jar Ky.jar`), I got this error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: KySim has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

The error on my friend's end was also relating to Java Runtime versions so maybe this is somehow connected? As a beginner, I've spent quite some time on this but haven't been able to come up with a solution or even an idea of what I need to do so any help is appreciated.

I don't know whether this is important but this is my Java version info:

```
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a version mismatch. You have compiled your code using java version 10 and your current JRE is version 8.

```
49 = Java 5
50 = Java 6
51 = Java 7
52 = Java 8
53 = Java 9
54 = Java 10
55 = Java 11
56 = Java 12
57 = Java 13
```

Comment: So I just need to update my JRE version?

Comment: yes you have to be in sync with your IDE jre and system jre